# How to create a new object of a given type in the constructor

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I am having trouble figuring out how to create a new object in the constructor based on the given type.

For instance, I have a robot driver that has a default constructor which takes no arguments and creates a basic robot. But I have another constructor that creates a new robot based on the argument.

```
public RobotDriver() {
   this.robot = new BasicRobot();
}

public RobotDriver(Robot robot) {
  //don't know what to do here...
}
```

`Robot` is an interface. So what if I want to create `RobotDriver` such that its `Robot` is of a different type like `AdvancedRobot`? Would I have to do some type of casting?

Comment: You don't want to use `this.robot = robot;`?

Comment: @TedHopp I was thinking of that. But what if I wanted to create a new one?

Comment: What is your problem? "this.robot = robot" is simple and good answer, I guess.

Comment: If it has a default constructor you can use `this.robot = robot.getClass().newInstance();` or if you define a copy method in the interface you can use `this.robot = robot.makeCopy();`. Finally, you can make robots cloneable. Take a look at the docs for `Object.clone()`.

Comment: @Fumu7 Hmm so the default constructor would create a new BasicRobot, but to create another type of robot, that type of robot would need to be created first and then passed into the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for a class that can create objects of any Robot type:RobotDriver / AdvanceRobot etc. If yes, then you need to look into Factory design pattern.

[Factory Pattern from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

> factory method pattern is a creational pattern which uses factory
>   methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without
>   specifying the exact class of object that will be created. This is
>   done by creating objects via calling a factory method—either specified
>   in an interface and implemented by child classes, or implemented in a
>   base class and optionally overridden by derived classes—rather than by
>   calling a constructor.

Comment: just noticed i was repeating you sorry. i think factory is a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to capture the constructor argument, you can use:

```
public RobotDriver(Robot robot) {
    this.robot = robot;
}
```

If you want to create a copy of the argument inside the constructor, there are several possibilities. If your `Robot` implementations all have a default constructor, you can do this:

```
public RobotDriver(Robot robot) {
    this.robot = robot.getClass().newInstance();
}
```

Failing that, you might modify your `Robot` interface to include a copy function:

```
public RobotDriver(Robot robot) {
    this.robot = robot.makeCopy();
}
```

Or you might make `Robot` a `Cloneable` class and modify the `Robot` interface to make `clone()` public (it's `protected` by default):

```
public RobotDriver(Robot robot) {
    this.robot = robot.clone();
}
```

(This is basically another version of `makeCopy()`.)

Finally, applying [Juned Ahsan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26199003/535871), you can define your `RobotDriver` constructor to take a factory as an argument or, for the default constructor, to have a settable static default factory:

```
public class RobotDriver {
    // basic robots by default
    private static RobotFactory defaultFactory = new BasicRobotFactory();
    private static RobotFactory factory = defaultFactory;

    public RobotDriver() {
        robot = factory.makeRobot();
    }

    /**
     * Change the factory for new instances of RobotDriver
     */
    public static void setFactory(RobotFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory == null ? defaultFactory : factory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you could extend the Robot class and create a new class called AdvancedRobot. You could then use polymorphism http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm. You would then ideally create logic in the newly created AdvancedRobot class to encapsulate an AdvancedRobot. If you set this up correctly, you will not need to do casting.